# PHP mkdir Permissions

Tags: php, linux, cpanel, mkdir

I have tried the following but it seems the folder gets created on the server (cPanel Linux) as `755` and not `777` why? and how could I make it write permission 777

```
mkdir($location.$folderName, 0777);
mkdir($location.$folderName, 777);
```

Comment: No can you give me an example @xanadont

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
chmod($location.$folderName, 0777);
```

Please see http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php for more examples and documentation in changing file mode

If you are still having problem ... sometimes you need to change ownership

```
 chown($location.$folderName, "root");
```

Please see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chown.php for documentation